# estimating frequency in timeseries

Tags: time-series

I have a statistical question that is difficult to explain, but I try. I appreciate it if you could give me some hints on this issue. My question is: Is there any statistical test or analysis that can be used to understand how frequency in a time series changes?  I am thinking about the frequency of occurrence.

Let me explain more specifically by an example. Look at the example below, there are two binary groups: Y1 and Y2 ... in Y1, as time passes the frequency of occurrence of number “1” is increasing, or let’s say number "1" is becoming more frequent. While in Y2, number "1" does not occur with a specific trend and occurs at random timesteps.
so how can we tell if the frequency of occurrence of number "1" is changing? and differentiate the two time series?

```
X   Y1  Y2
1   1   1
2   0   0
3   0   0
4   0   0
5   0   0
6   0   1
7   0   0
8   0   1
9   0   0
10  0   0
11  1   1
12  0   1
13  0   0
14  0   0
15  0   0
16  0   1
17  0   0
18  0   1
19  1   0
20  0   0
21  0   1
22  0   0
23  0   0
24  0   0
25  0   0
26  0   1
27  1   0
28  1   0
29  0   1
30  0   0
31  0   1
32  0   0
33  0   0
34  0   1
35  0   0
36  1   1
37  1   0
38  0   0
39  0   0
40  0   0
41  0   1
42  1   0
43  0   0
44  0   1
45  0   0
46  1   1
47  0   0
48  0   0
49  1   0
50  0   0
51  1   1
```